# User to user messaging on Google Cloud Messaging

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-messaging

I have setup Google Cloud Messaging on Google App Engine. I have successfully managed to implement downstream messaging to an Android client.

I have the following questions regarding the usage of GCM:

- Does it allow user to user messaging?
- Where can I check the delivery status of upstream messages?
- If user to user is not possible, what's the solution to setup a basic chat between users using GCM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can consider this implementation to work with GCM

```
     Device A ------> Your Server ------> GCM Server ------> Device B
     Device B ------> Your Server ------> GCM Server ------> Device A
```

**1. Does it allow user to user messaging?**

- To create a user to user messaging, you can use device to send a request to the GCM server and vice-versa for the corresponding device as illustrated above.

**2. Where can I check the delivery status of upstream messages?**

- I refer the delivery status of the upstream message as the recipient getting a message on his device. When the recipient receives his message, you can send an acknowledge back to your server to indicate the success.
- Alternatively, you can also check the status of your message being sent to your server and the GCM server if you wish to simplify the process.

Hope this helps!